# Center alignments greyed out in Xcode 7.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout

Why are the the vertical and horizontal center alignments greyed out?

[image]

Comment: Any context? It seems weird though.

Comment: I add a brand new UIViewControll, and add one UILabel, still greyed out..

Comment: Are you selecting two or more views? I think these constraints only apply to a group of two or more views.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks! But how do you center one single UILabel with autolayout then?

Comment: I normally use `ctrl` drag one view to its container and select **Center Horizontally** or/and *Center Vertically* respectively. (well, _center_ should always to a one-to-one relationship i think)

Comment: @J.Wang Thanks ! You should post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I know it`s been a while since this question has been asked, but in case someone is still stuck with this problem: If "Add Constrains" is greyed out like in the screenshot above, check the Layout-Settings. Layout should be Inferred (Constrains). Once you change this setting from Autoresizing mask to Inferred (Constrains), the "Add Constrains"-Button is selectable.
[change the Layout-Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1F6v.png)